# Check if specific date isToday (or passed) Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

via dateformatter, how can I write a function to know if a specific date has passed or is today?

example: March 8, 2020

Date()

```
    if Date() >= 28March2020 {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Do you care about timezones?

Comment: @Sweeper no. the important thing is that it is my specific data (obviously go to get the current local of the country) and compare it with today.

Comment: So you want to see if the user's _local_ time has passed a certain _local_ date. Correct?

Comment: @Sweeper I just want to check that example: today> = 8March2020. (therefore of a specific date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
if Date() >= Calendar.current.dateWith(year: 2020, month: 3, day: 28) ?? Date.distantFuture {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

where `dateWith(year:month:day:)` is defined as:

```
extension Calendar {
    func dateWith(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date? {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.year = year
        dateComponents.month = month
        dateComponents.day = day
        return date(from: dateComponents)
    }
}
```

This method basically returns the `Date` with the specified year, month, and day, with the hour, minute, and second components all being 0, that is, start of the specified day. In other words, I am checking whether the instant now is after the start of the day 2020-03-28.

Answer (score 1):

This simple `Date` extension should do the trick

```
extension Date {
    func isToday() -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) == Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
}
```

And to use it just do something like:

```
if someDate.isToday() {
    // it is today!
} else {
    // not today
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way and most flexible is to convert it to seconds and then compare.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
let today = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let date1 = formatter.date(from: "2022-10-01")!.timeIntervalSince1970
let date2 = formatter.date(from: "2022-10-02")!.timeIntervalSince1970
if today >= date1 && today <= date2 {

}
```